# Is it possible for terraform to install providers for foreign architectures?

Tags: terraform

I work on MacOS to write terraform, the build pipelines that apply terraform run on Linux.

When I update a terraform provider locally on my mac and then commit `version.tf` and `.terraform.lock.hcl` it puts the new hash in for mac, but not linux.

When the build pipeline does a `terraform init`, the linux version of the provider is downloaded and it's hash added to `.terraform.lock.hcl`. I want the build to fail if the git working copy is dirty.

Is it possible from my mac to generate and add the hash to the terraform for linux from mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `providers` option to select which platforms [1] you wish to use, e.g.:

```bash
terraform providers lock -platform=darwin_amd64 -platform=linux_amd64
```

It will create a lock file with checksums for different architectures.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/providers/lock#specifying-target-platforms

Answer (score 1):

By default Terraform will install all providers from their primary registry (`registry.terraform.io` unless another hostname is specified in the provider address), and when it does so it will record the full set of checksums that was signed by the provider developer, which covers all platforms.

There are a few different ways you can break this and make Terraform only record checksums for the current architecture:

- Use [a `provider_installation` block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#provider-installation) to explicitly tell Terraform to install a particular provider from a local filesystem directory or a network mirror.
- Place a provider in one of [the implied mirror directories](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#implied-local-mirror-directories), which causes Terraform to prefer to install that provider from the local copy rather than the primary registry.
- Enable the [provider plugin cache](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#provider-plugin-cache) and therefore cause subsequent installations of the same provider to come from the local cache directory instead of the primary registry.

If you are in any of these situations then Terraform will be unable to use the signed checksums from the primary registry and so it will instead need to rely only on a checksum calculated locally, which means it can only record the checksum for the current platform since that is the only package that your local Terraform has access to.

---

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to leave Terraform with its default provider installation settings and therefore let Terraform access the full set of checksums from the primary registry.

If you cannot use the primary registry for some special reason then you can tell Terraform to download the packages for a specified set of platforms and calculate checksums for them locally using [the `terraform providers lock` command](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/providers/lock):

```
terraform providers lock \
  -platform=linux_amd64 \
  -platform=windows_amd64 \
  -platform=darwin_amd64
```

The `terraform providers lock` command ignores the CLI configuration's provider installation settings in favor of its own arguments, and so by default it will retrieve the packages from the primary registry for each provider you are using and then calculate checksums based on those packages.